# Mod_jk will not load in Apache 2

Tags: macos, apache2, xampp, tomcat6, mod-jk

I need some help getting this to work.  It's starting to get on my nerves and I'm sure I'm missing some bizzarely simple and easy oversight somewhere to get this to work.  I have Apache 2 setup with XAMPP.  I'm running snow leopard 10.6, I have Tomcat running on localhost:8080 just fine.  I made and installed the mod_jk.c and is in /usr/libexec/apache2

When I put in this code:

```
LoadModule jk_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so
```

Apache says back to me:

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so into server: cannot create object file image or add library`

I've re-installed mod_jk a couple times.  I've placed it in different spots by the "cp" command (like /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/) and nothing seems to work.  Running out of options to get this to work.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

do you have something like APACHE_DIR/modules/?
are you sure you .so file is not corrupted? or what version you have? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I have two places where Apache resides it seems.  One that comes with the OS of Macs Snow Leopard (and I do have Xcode) and XAMPP's apache directory.  This is where I'm thinking the problem lies.  Maybe.  And I am at 64 bit.

Comment: Oh and the library where the apache commands reside (.so files) are in /usr/libexec/apache2